# Sticky HTML table header almost works, but rows slightly visible above header

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm using a React table library called react-bootstrap-table2. It doesn't have a way to make the top row sticky, so I added the following CSS:

```
.table-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.react-bootstrap-table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

The resulting table header is now sticky, but as I scroll through the rows, I can see a few pixels of the row at the top of the header. If you look at the image below under "Sample Table", you'll see what look like dots. But if I add `padding: 10px;` to the CSS, it becomes apparent that it's row content that's appearing above the header. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-2-iu7f2)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those "little pixels" that you see are basically **the data on the table**. I would move slightly more above. Use

```
.react-bootstrap-table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-table-2-wppbz?file=/src/styles.css